# Wordpress Edit Button not appearing for widget in customizer

Tags: wordpress, widget

The pencil icon is not appearing above my widget in the customizer front-end view.

I registered the widget as follows:

```html
function jwd_widgets_init()
{

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
        register_sidebar(array(
          'name'          => esc_html__('Widget ' .$i, 'jwd'),
          'id'            => 'widget-' .$i,
          'description'   => esc_html__('Add widgets here.', 'jwd'),
          'before_widget' => '',
          'after_widget'  => '',
      ));
    }

}
add_action('widgets_init', 'jwd_widgets_init');
```

In my PHP template, this is how I call the widget in question (widget-1)

```html
<?php if (is_active_sidebar("widget-1")): ?>
  <?php dynamic_sidebar("widget-1") ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The widget itself works. I'm staring at it in the customizer. I can access it through the widgets menu in customizer, but it would be a lot more convenient to have that pencil icon as a shortcut, like with the nav menus.

Answer (score -1):

use below hook

```html
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize )
{
   //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

for further help read :- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register